# Marketplace API for Paytm, Myntra and Jabong

Tags: api, marketplace, paytm

Do Myntra, Paytm and Jabong provide APIs for Marketplace Integration?
I need Order and Catalog for syncing with my system. Flipkart and Amazon already have API developed for this purpose. For example, Flipkart provides: https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIOverview.html
to interact with Order Data.

Is there any similar sort of thing for Myntra, Jabong and Paytm?

Comment: Quora is a better place for these kinds of question. 
paytm - http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/discussion/topic/integration-application-with-paytm-marketplace/ 
Jabong - http://support.unicommerce.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2504720-integrating-with-jabong-marketplace 
Since Filpkart is the parent company of Myntra and Jabong, get in touch with touch for more information on marketplace apis. Not sure if they have developed somethings before being acquired by Flipkart.